# rgdal installation failed on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, gdal, rgdal

I am trying to install rgdal in my computer that runs ubuntu linux 14.04. The R version that I am using is: 3.3.1. I installed gdal and related packages from the regular ubuntu repository and also using the ubuntu-gis ppa (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). In both cases, I've got the same error message while compiling:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal  -I"/home/magdiel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/sp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c inverser.c -o inverser.o
inverser.c:3:22: fatal error: projects.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
 #include <projects.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [inverser.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rgdal’
```

I had rgdal installed before without problem and was trying to update it to a newer version as required for R.

I will greatly appreciate any help

Comment: [Here is what worked for me](http://askubuntu.com/a/725675/458220), back in January of this year, with Ubuntu 14.04.2 and with R 3.2.2. If my solution doesn't work for you, perhaps see the other older answers over there, for additional ideas. Best of  luck!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien; it might be worth writing it up here as well ; I just tried your solution and it works (I also needed to install `libgdal-dev` and  `libmysqlclient-dev`, but the dependency notices give these)

Comment: Sure, why not. I don't think it can actually hurt to have it both places.

Answer (score 3):

In February 2016, on Ubuntu 14.04.2 (and with R 3.2.2), I needed the following to get both [**rgdal**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) and the complementary (and frequently very useful) [**gdalUtils**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/index.html) package installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libgdal1h
sudo apt-get -y install libgdal1-dev
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
Rscript 'install.packages(c("rgdal", "gdalUtils"))'
```

Comment: Yeah. I should just remove my idle speculation.

Comment: I've noticed that it's often necessary to install `*-dev` versions on Linux which I assume is needed to support proper linkage with external applications.