# how to install rgdal package

Tags: r, rstudio, rgdal

I have been faced a problem when I tried ti install rgdal package in rstudio. Terminal caught this: `Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status`

I tried this: `> install.packages('rgdal',repos="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin")`
 but terminal caught: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rgdal’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)`

I tried to reinstal sp. No reslut. How to fix it??
OS - Elementary OS 5.0
r version - 3.5.2

Comment: do you get any other errors? linux based os's need some other non-r packages: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382368/rgdal-installation-difficulty-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213027/rgdal-installation-failed-on-ubuntu-14-04) *might* help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to run `install.packages('rgdal')`. R will ask you to select a mirror where the "0-Cloud [https]" mirror should work. The package rgdal is available there. The mentioned repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin does not provide the R package.

Comment: when i run install.packages('rgdal')  terminal caught:  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: The R instance where you try to install this package, can you ensure that you have the permission to install libraries? When the R libraries folder is write protected, then this error may occur.

Comment: @Tyomik_mnemonic: did you check the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html)? It looks like you need a couple of non-R dependencies to be installed first.

Comment: It looks similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386372/r-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-forecast) regarding package loading.

Comment: @bob1 CRAN depends are ok. What did you mean about  a couple of non-R dependencies to be installed first? gdal fo example?

Comment: @Tyomik_mnemonic, correct, though now that I look at it, these seem to be R dependencies that just need to be installed before rgdal.

Comment: @bob1 I solve problem by instailing packages: $sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev and $sudo apt-get install libgdal-doc. I find it by $ apt-file search gdal-config.